# If the batsman gets out hit wicket, but the bowler bowls a no ball, is the wicket rescinded?

Tags: rules, cricket, wicket

Wondering because if the batsman hits his own stumps, most of the time it isn't directly due to the bowler. Hit wicket in on itself is a fairly rare form of dismissal anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, never mind. Law 21.18 states that hit wicket is not one of the select four forms of batsman dismissal that can occur on a no ball.